# Conditional formatting php table

Tags: php, formatting, conditional-statements

I need help with a simple task, but I am stuck...
I have a database where I pull different data and I am visualizing those data on a web page.
Here is my query for getting the data:

```php
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT *, DATEDIFF(nextcalibration, CURDATE()) AS days FROM tools AS dp ");
```

Here is my table:

```php
<table id="table_id" class="table table-striped">

<tr>
    <th>Nr</th> <th>Status</th> <th>name</th> <th>Serial</th> <th>Used At</th> <th>Owner</th> <th>Calibrated</th> <th>nextcalibration</th> <th>vendor</th> <th>days</th> <th>actions</th>
</tr>
<?php

while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['toolnr']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['status']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['toolname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['serial']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['usedat']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['owner']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['calibrated']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['nextcalibration']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['vendors']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['days']. "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=$user_data[id]'><img src='img/edit.png' ></a> | <a href='delete.php?id=$user_data[id]' onclick='return checkDelete()'><img src='img/delete.png'></a></td></tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

I would like to make conditional formatting only for the last column - `"days"`.
The idea is if the value of `"days" <= 30` to become red color text.
I tried with various JS, but honestly, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table id="table_id" class="table table-striped">

<tr>
    <th>Nr</th> <th>Status</th> <th>name</th> <th>Serial</th> <th>Used At</th> <th>Owner</th> <th>Calibrated</th> <th>nextcalibration</th> <th>vendor</th> <th>days</th> <th>actions</th>
</tr>
<?php

while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['toolnr']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['status']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['toolname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['serial']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['usedat']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['owner']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['calibrated']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['nextcalibration']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['vendors']."</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    $days=$user_data['days'];
    if($days <= 30){
        echo "<span style='color:red;'>$days</span>";
    }else{
        echo $days;
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=$user_data[id]'><img src='img/edit.png' ></a> | <a href='delete.php?id=$user_data[id]' onclick='return checkDelete()'><img src='img/delete.png'></a></td></tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: Very good Mustafa, thank you!
It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Would something simple like this - without JS- work?

```
<table id="table_id" class="table table-striped">

<tr>
    <th>Nr</th> <th>Status</th> <th>name</th> <th>Serial</th> <th>Used At</th> <th>Owner</th> <th>Calibrated</th> <th>nextcalibration</th> <th>vendor</th> <th>days</th> <th>actions</th>
</tr>
<?php

while($user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $style_days=($user_data['days']<=30)?'style="color:red"':'';
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['toolnr']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['status']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['toolname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['serial']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['usedat']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['owner']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['calibrated']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['nextcalibration']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$user_data['vendors']."</td>";
    echo "<td ".$style_days.">".$user_data['days']. "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=$user_data[id]'><img src='img/edit.png' ></a> | <a href='delete.php?id=$user_data[id]' onclick='return checkDelete()'><img src='img/delete.png'></a></td></tr>";
}

?>
</table>
```

Of course, apply the necessary guarding for `$user_data['days']` (existence, numeric..) :)